# Groovy half-exclusive range strange behaviour

Tags: groovy

This is a code sample from the book *"Groovy in Action"*. Why is **Groovy** showing this behaviour when using half-exclusive range. It is supposed to return all but the last element in the range but it sometimes show all elements in the range plus one.

**This is the sample.**

```
 class Weekday implements Comparable {
    static final DAYS = [
        'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'
    ]
    private int idx = 0

    Weekday(index)     { idx = index }
    Weekday next()     { new Weekday(idx+1) }
    Weekday previous() { new Weekday(idx+1) }
    int compareTo(Object other) { this.idx <=> other.idx }

    String toString() {
        def index = idx % DAYS.size()
        while (index < 0 ) index += DAYS.size()
            DAYS[index]
    }
}

def mon = new Weekday(1)
def fri = new Weekday(5)

7.times { mon++ } // Monday following week

println fri.idx   //  5
println mon.idx   //  8

println 5 .. 8    // [5, 6, 7, 8]
println fri..mon  // [Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon] Ok without half-exclusive
println 5 ..< 8   // [5, 6, 7]
println fri..<mon // [Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue] ????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previous()` should be `idx - 1` instead of `idx + 1`:

```
Weekday previous() { new Weekday(idx-1) }
```

Might be a copy paste typo.

Comment: I made a mistake when copying the samples. I checked the book after your answer and realized the mistake was mine. Thanks.